# I want a Solution in form of SQL query or other logic for C# desktop app to calculate daily sale of current month

Tags: c#, sql

I have Table  Daily_Sale. Sample is

```
     Date_Time             Sale      Cost     Profit    Margin

Friday, June 29, 2018      33945     20000    13945     41.081
Monday, April 16, 2018     63303     43000    20303     32.072
Saturday, April 14, 2018   104534    74000    30534     29.209
Sunday, April 15, 2018     9800      70000    28000     28.571
Thursday, June 28, 2018    27156     16000    11156     41.081
Tuesday, May 1, 2018       17034     12000    5034      29.552
Wednesday, May 2, 2018     19753     12000    7752      39.246
```

I want to calculate sale of current month.Actually I want to show sale,cost profit and margin in datagridview and chart of current month.

I'm trying

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Daily_Sale ", con);

adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
dt = new DataTable();
adapt.Fill(dt);
bsource = new BindingSource();
bsource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;

chart1.Series["Sale"].XValueMember = "Total_Sale";
chart1.Series["Sale"].YValueMembers = "Total_Sale";
chart1.Series["Profit"].XValueMember = "Total_Profit";
chart1.Series["Profit"].YValueMembers = "Total_sale";
chart1.Series["Margin"].XValueMember = "Margin";
chart1.Series["Margin"].YValueMembers = "Total_sale";
chart1.DataSource = hJSportsDataSet8.Daily_Sale;
chart1.DataBind();


cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Daily_Sale ";
SqlDataReader reader;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{

    chart1.Series["Sale"].XValueMember = "Date_Time";
    chart1.Series["Sale"].YValueMembers = "Total_Sale";
    chart1.Series["Profit"].XValueMember = "Date_Time";
    chart1.Series["Profit"].YValueMembers = "Total_Profit";
    chart1.Series["Margin"].XValueMember = "Date_Time";
    chart1.Series["Margin"].YValueMembers = "Margin";
}
```

But I'm Sure this show the entirely table data.
According to above sample data, for example current month is April and current day is 17 April ,I want to show sale of current table.(Out put)

```
    Date_Time              Sale      Cost     Profit    Margin
Monday, April 17, 2018     63303     43000    20303     32.072
Saturday, April 14, 2018   104534    74000    30534     29.209
Sunday, April 15, 2018     9800      70000    28000     28.571

Today's Sale =63303 Total Sale of Month= 177637
```

I'm new Please help me, I  already waste my 3 days but got not appreciable solution.

Comment: Add where condition and filter in SQL. Match Month and Year of column to month and year of getdate.

Comment: so add a where clause to the SQL.. we aint going to be writing it for you

Comment: I have single column for month and year for date which is Date_time i have already mention my database table in  sample.Because I'm taking date from datetimepicker and save date above format. @Aswani Madhavan

Comment: @hamidjalil type of that column?

Comment: I tried both varchar and date type to save date taking from datetimepicker. it save in that format "Monday, April 17, 2018".I know this is string when i retrieve from database which cause difficulty and problem to to compare in sql query

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan thanx a lot.. yes your suggestion works

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trying different queries a simple suggestion of @AswaniMadhavan works . it's simple

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Daily_Sale Where Month(Date_Time)=Month( 
getDate() ) ", con);
```

Actually I change my Date_Time  format in SQL database from varchar to DateTime and I realize as a beginner that it's best practice to save Date and time in datetime format rather a character or string, to avoid from further problems.
so before insert into Daily Sale I just wrote this code

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";

cmd_dily_sale = new SqlCommand("insert into Daily_Sale(Date_Time,Total_Sale,Total_Cost,Total_Profit,Margin)values(@Date_Time,@Total_Sale,@Total_Cost,@Total_Profit,@Margin)", con);
                cmd_dily_sale.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Time", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                cmd_dily_sale.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Sale", sale);
                cmd_dily_sale.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Cost", total_cost);
                cmd_dily_sale.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Profit", profit);
                cmd_dily_sale.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Margin", margin);
                cmd_dily_sale.ExecuteNonQuery();
```